# Apple Watch Voice Memos cannot be retrieved

Tags: backup, apple-watch, voice-memo

I have been using the **Apple Watch Series 6** to record voice memos for the past three weeks.

Every evening, the watch rests on its charging dock and the paired **iPhone 12 Pro** is charged next to it. I sometimes turn off the phone if I sleep or put it in plane mode, but not always.

Day after day, I noticed the **Voice Memos** *never* backed up to the phone. Not even once. They just added up in the watch and the watch's app has zero option to transfer manually.

But I had to keep working and making recordings.

I tried everything that people suggested, like turning off the phone and the watch simultaneously, going on/off plane mode, etc but nothing would sync, day after day after day, I was never able to see the memos on the phone.

Today, after reading [this article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250666187), I decided to address this problem which was blocking me in my work, and un-paired and re-paired the watch. There was a recent backup of the watch dating from today.

Unfortunately, after I did this, **all the voice memos were gone from the watch**.

And they are not on the phone either.

If it means I have lost three weeks of work, this is a real nightmare.

Can the memos be retrieved? I am using the latest watch and the latest phone... and they never synced once.
For 3 weeks, nothing would sync into the phone and I couldn't access my work, so I had to find a solution. Now I can't even access them on the watch...

**I'm trying to understand:**

-What triggers the transfer of the Voice memos from the Watch to the iPhone? Can it be manually activated? None of the watch recordings ever transferred to the phone, ever.

-Why did the recent backup listed on my phone not include the Voice Memos? How did that qualify as a backup? If I could access these backups from the iPhone's backed up iTunes data, where would I look for the Watch recordings?

Comment: So it did not work on day 1 and you continued for another 20 days? Without using a different method in parallel? Even a digital note recorder? I hate to suggest this but there may not be any copy anywhere...

Comment: I was working abroad and did not have other options. And placing my trust in the newest versions of both the hardware and software that exist, I guess? If I've lost everything it really would suck (recordings of old people talking about their past), but it looks like it's bound to happen again and not sync (I just tried again. I record. I stop the recording. I wait. Nothing syncs). Which is really depressing. The good news is that I documented visually with a 35mm film camera, and at least physical supports are reliable. I just won't have the audio matching it. And no solution for the future.

Comment: I just tested and can confirm that the transfer happens automatically on my device, within just a minute. I did not need to plug into charging. I'm testing now whether this happens via iCloud.

Comment: I don't believe this uses iCloud. When I turned off my phone, my computer did not see new recordings. When I turned my phone back on, my computer saw the recording I made on my watch shortly thereafter.

Comment: My guess is that the backup did not include it because the watch is not supposed to be the primary record for voice memos. If it can transfer for a backup, it would transfer it to the phone and make the phone the primary record. This is why your watch backup also doesn't contain photos - even though you have photos on your watch.

Comment: You lost me with the third comment - the watch has an app called "Voice Memos" - which is not intended to access the voice memos recorded on the phone, but to record its own memos. Not sure what you mean with "and make the phone the primary record". And I don't have photos on my watch. Are you using a AW 6 and a iPhone 12 Pro? Try with a longer recording made on the watch, i.e. 2 hours long and tell me if it's instant.

Comment: @MicroMachine When I say "primary record" I don't mean record as in record voice, I mean record as in record keeping. The watch is intended to offload the recording to the phone at its earliest convenience. Clearly this isn't working properly in your case - but that's why it's not in the backup, since it's not meant to remain on the watch.

Comment: @Ezekiel I wonder what's supposed to trigger the offloading of the recordings to the phone, and what makes that bit of code not run properly. I'll probably end up having to schedule a Genius Bar appointment but maybe this port would help if we knew how to use it https://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/05/19/how-to-access-apple-watch-diagnostic-port/